# Reuse common key values across different jSON files

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I have json files for all my environments, and common key values are used across all the environment specific JSON files. So I want to know that, is there any way to not write the same string every where but define all the string at one place as variables and reuse them ? Rewriting the same strings again and agai is error prone also. The justification is same as why we use variables and not hard coded strings in our code

Framework : C#, .net core

Comment: It depends. You haven't told us what programming language / build environment this is being used in.

Comment: C#, .net core framework

Comment: please use the "edit" button to add that information clearly to your question, and also add some suitable blue tags so that people with an interest and knowledge in these topics will be more likely to see your question. Also, please state the version of .NET Core, and maybe also what IDE you are using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For reusing strings across multiple configuration files, `ConfigurationBuilder` is available in .Net Core. Through [ConfigurationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0), one can reuse add up and override strings.

Here is a simple example which I used recently:

https://lukemerrett.com/environment-specific-configuration-in-dotnet-core/